# Javascript/AJAX Error 404 Not found or Undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I have a page which loops down the first column and copies the value to a text box, and then it is supposed to query `data.asp`, but I keep getting an error of either 
`GET http://192.168.1.12/pb_search/v2/demo/data.asp?h_prodref=undefined 404 (Not Found)` 
or 
`XHR finished loading: GET "http://192.168.1.12/pb_search/v2/demo/data.asp?h_prodref=undefined"`. Errors from Google Chrome Developer Tools.

Both my scripts work independently, but when I piece them together, I get these erorors. I am probably missing something really simple, but I very much learning this on the fly, so any help would be appreciated.

**Full Code**

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="16%" class="prodref">84PS01</td>
    <td width="51%"><input type="text" class="h_prodref" /><button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button></td>
    <td width="33%" id="demo">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">92K002</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="h_prodref" /><button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button></td>
    <td id="demo">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">68F017</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="h_prodref" /><button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button></td>
    <td id="demo">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
    var prodref = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref");
    var h_prodref = document.getElementsByClassName("h_prodref");
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < prodref.length; i++) {
    h_prodref[i].value = prodref[i].innerHTML;
function loadDoc() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("h_prodref");
    x[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("h_prodref").value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?h_prodref="+x[i].value, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
    }
</script>
```

Comment: function loadDoc() inside for loop?

Comment: Don't I need that to call the function?

Comment: you can define the function outside the loop and inside loop you can just call it.SOmething like this https://jsfiddle.net/27tL0mcu/

Comment: For starters the line `xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?h_prodref="+x[i].value, true);` contains an undefined value `x[i].value`. The javascript code looks weird you have a `for` statement surrounding the `function`?

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for the comment. With reference to the line `xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?h_prodref="+x[i].value, true);` the `x[i].value` is their as I thought it was needed to loop. The function works on a seperate page where it is just the function.

Comment: Like I've said the structure of your javascript is strange. You don't need to call the function defintion within a loop just make a reference to it i.e `loadDoc();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### So What's the Problem?

The value `undefined` is getting added into AJAX call that is made instead of the expected value of `x[i].value`. I'm making an assumption here though and that is that

```
http://192.168.1.12/pb_search/v2/demo/data.asp
```

exists and the `HTTP 404 Not Found` is being forced by the `data.asp` script as a scripted response and not because the server can't find the `data.asp` page.

#### Restructuring the JavaScript

When calling a `function` you don't need the entire definition at the point where you want to call it, if this was the case you would have the same function being duplicated throughout the code where it is called breaking fundamental principles in programming like [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Here is a quick example of restructuring the JavaScript code:

```
var prodref = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref");
var h_prodref = document.getElementsByClassName("h_prodref");
var i = 0;
for (i; i < prodref.length; i++) {
  h_prodref[i].value = prodref[i].innerHTML;
  // Call function inside the loop
  loadDoc();
}

// Definition should be defined once
function loadDoc() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("h_prodref");
  x[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("h_prodref").value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?h_prodref="+x[i].value, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: In my function I use `[i]` instead of `[0]` which I originally had, but this only worked for the first item.  Now I get an error defining `[i]` should I not be defining `[i]`.

Comment: @JonathanGriffin `i` is defined in the global scope in the example `var i = 0;`. You then iterate through with the `for` incrementing the `i` variable. If you add a `var i;` in the `loadDoc()` function you will lose the reference to the global `i` variable. This isn't ideal and there are better ways of approaching this like passing the value in the arguments rather then using global references, but I haven't got into that here just the simplest example of your code snippet to hopefully get you on track.